# Pass UDF method as parameter to other UDF in KSQL

Tags: apache-kafka, user-defined-functions, ksqldb

I am implementing custom library (using UDFs) for KSQL engine and I wonder how to solve one of the issues I have.

I have defined a couple of UDFs which do something with parameters passed and return some output.
Now, I need to pass those UDFs (their calls) into other UDF.
So the structure would look like this:

***SELECT * FROM stream s WHERE UDF_1(UDF_11(s.param1, s.param2), UDF_12(s.param3, s.param4), ...) EMIT CHANGES;***

Is it possible to do define the UDF which takes other UDFs as arguments? If yes, how can I achieve it?
If not, please share the idea you have on how I can solve the problem.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: I didn't think about it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're asking about what the parameters for the method definition should be?

A UDF would return a single value, and the functions would be evaluated inside out, so they are not "taking UDFs as parameters", just the return value, which would generally be a primitive java type

For example, if you split a string column, then cast it to an int, that'd have to look like `CAST(STRSPLIT(c, delim)[0] AS INT)`, where the cast operator takes any Object (here a string), and returns an integer, which could be passed further to more UDFs